# JSP page not reading submitted for values

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am working on the front end of a jsp based app. We're using spring running on weblogic.

I have a page with a form that submits to itself and I am trying to access the values of hidden fields that I set with javascript.

```
 <form method="post">

  <input type="hidden" name="choosenDateFrom" value="test1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="choosenDateTo" value="test2"  />
.... more code
```

However when I use the code on the same page:

```
 <c:choose>
  <c:when test="${param.choosenDateFrom!=null}">
   <c:out value="${param.choosenDateFrom}" />
 </c:when>
   </c:choose>
```

The params are not shown on the page. What am I missing? I though this is the standard way of doing this.

Could it be that since we are using a MVC framework I can't pass params around like this?

Comment: Could you show the controller's code for this JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have JSTL installed in webapp and declared in JSP?

Check the generated HTML output (open page in browser, choose *View Source*). It should contain **no** traces of any JSTL code. If it does, then you likely just need to install JSTL first. Just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and declare the taglib in top of JSP as per the [JSTL core TLD](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

If that still doesn't solve the problem, then there's apparently means of a brand new request (i.e. a *redirect* has occurred), or you were using wrong parameter names. Use `<c:out value="${pageContext.request.parameterMap}" />` to see all names.

As per your doubt:

> *Could it be that since we are using a MVC framework I can't pass params around like this?*

That purely depends on which one you're using. Not mentioning it doesn't help us to give better answers. But in general the `${param}` should be left untouched.

Comment: yes we have the include
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
What else could I be missing...

Comment: How does the generated HTML output look? Have you checked it at any way?

Comment: html is fine, no traces of jsp, there could be a redirect happening here

Comment: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects$5@5956375 is what gets printed out in the html when I use <c:out value="${param}" />

Comment: Oh yeah, I incorrectly expected it to be a `Map`. Do a `${pageContext.request.parameterMap}` instead. Anyway, if there's means of a redirect, then the initial request, including all of its parameters and attributes are obviously unavailable in the redirected request.

Answer (score 0):

have you included the core lib in your jsp? Most of the the cases that what happens and jsp just ignores your syntax.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Firefox plugin named Tamper Data to see if your parameters are actually being posted correctly. Verify that you are not doing a redirect after post because you would loose all your parameters since it asks the browser to perform a new request.